# OCMock -[NSURLSessionDataTask response] unrecognized selector crash in iOS 9

Tags: unit-testing, cocoa-touch, ios9, ocmock, nsurlsessiondatatask

### The problem

We use OCMock for mock objects in many of our unit tests. As part of our tests to see how our code responds to server responses, we create an NSURLSessionDataTask object and later try to use the "response" property on it.

### The plot thickens

Prior to iOS 9 the tests ran just fine. The property also works correctly in the normal callback flow of the app on iOS 9.

However, with the iOS 9 betas the tests crash at runtime with an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error. The property is present in the framework header and is not marked as removed in the documentation.

This sample code illustrates the issue:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSessionDataTask alloc] init];

NSLog(@"%@", task.response);
```

### A theory

It seems that a straight instantiation of the class no longer gives the property at runtime. It seems that the property is an `@dynamic` property that is generated at runtime using a different path of instantiation.

### The Question

How do I work around this issue in unit test OCMock objects in a way that would be backwards compatible with running the unit tests on iOS 8?

#### Update 1

Updating OCMock to the latest (3.1.5) does not fix the issue.

For additional context, here is how we are using `NSURLSessionDataTask` with OCMock. The tests fail on the third line.

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSessionDataTask alloc] init];
OCMockObject *mockTask = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:task];
[[[mockTask stub] andReturn:urlResponse] response];
```

Comment: Can you quote the actual error instead of describing it?  I'm wondering whether there are any extra clues in the phrasing.

Comment: "Unrecognized selector" is a pretty common error when calling a method that doesn't exist. The only extra bit of info in there that I didn't already quote is the memory address: '-[NSURLSessionDataTask response]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fde8e00af60'

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/issues/215. Looks like it was fixed in OCMock?

Comment: The updated OCMock still produces errors related to this: `"-[NSURLSessionDataTask response]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbee2f1caf0”`and `"OCPartialMockObject(NSURLSessionDataTask): cannot stub/expect/verify method 'response' because no such method exists in the mocked class.”`

Comment: The changes discussed in https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/pull/215 are implemented in https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/pull/223. These changes are not in OCMock 3.1.5. They will only be included in a future release. Can you try against master to see whether these changes do/will address your problem?

Comment: @ErikDoernenburg verified that master (at `25e68089e201140332aed16e042afc99c7b7d737`) resolves this issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCMock 3.2 is available now, which fixes this problem.

The fix was ["Add ability and tests for mocking dynamic properties"](https://github.com/imhuntingwabbits/ocmock/commit/e28b05e).